# How to remove reference and Use vba code for every machine?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, runtime-error

As you suggested I have done changes but still I am not able to make it user-friendly or you can say every time when i have to use this code I have to turn on Scripting Runtime on different computers.

Please suggest and make my code corrected as soon as possible

```
Sub GetFileNamesandPageCount()
    Option Explicit
    Public fs As Object

    Dim diaFolder As FileDialog
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim fld As Object
        Dim T_Str As String
        Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
        diaFolder.Show
    If diaFolder.Show = -1 Then
        T_Str = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Set diaFolder = Nothing
    End If
        Set fld = fs.getfolder(T_Str)
        Dim wdOBJ As Word.Application
        Dim wdDoc As Object
        Dim fd As Object

        Sheet1.UsedRange.Clear
        Sheet1.Range("A1") = "Document Name"
        Sheet1.Range("B1") = "Page Count"
        Sheet1.Range("A1:B1").Font.Bold = True
        Sheet1.Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 70
        Sheet1.Columns("B:B").AutoFit
        Sheet1.Range("A1:B1").Interior.ColorIndex = 37
        fs.GetSpecialFolder (1)
        Set wdOBJ = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        wdOBJ.Visible = True
        i = 1

        For Each fd In fld.Files
            If (InStr(1, fd, ".doc") > 0) Or (InStr(1, fd, ".docx") > 0) Or (InStr(1, fd, ".docm") > 0) Or (InStr(1, fd, ".doct") > 0) Or (InStr(1, fd, ".pdf") > 0) Then
                Sheet1.Range("A" & i + 1) = fd.Name
                Set wdDoc = wdOBJ.Documents.Open(CStr(fd))
                wdDoc.ComputeStatistics (wdStatisticPages)
                Sheet1.Range("B" & i + 1) = wdDoc.BuiltinDocumentProperties(14)

                wdDoc.Close False
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Next fd

        wdOBJ.Quit False

    End Sub
```

Comment: We are not a code review website, and neither is Stackoverflow, this question is outside the scope of Superuser

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Typically users here want to see what you've tried to solve your problem, just so it's clear that you aren't asking "Hey, will someone do my work for me?" If you add a little detail showing what you've tried or what ideas you have but don't know how to implement, you're more likely to get upvotes and answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you Instantiate wdOBJ as late binding, you should dimension it as Object, not as Word.Application. After that you should be able to remove the reference.